# Datatype detection cell by cell in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I am trying to retrieve the datatypes of the values in each cell of a pandas dataframe using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

dfin = pd.read_csv(path, dtype=object)

d = {"<class 'datetime.datetime'>":'DateTime.Type',
     "<class 'int'>": 'int',
     "<class 'float'>": 'float',
     "<class 'str'>": 'str'}

dftypes = df.applymap(type).astype(str).replace(d)
```

My dataframe contains mixed type columns and the 'dtype = object' parameter is intended to protect the types of cell values from being auto defined on a by column basis.

This code generates and maps the proper datatypes when the dfin is read from an xlsx file (*pd.read_xlsx()*), but not when read from a standard csv file (*pd.read_csv()*).

I want to be able to read in the data from a csv and then determine the datatypes cell by cell, but it only detects as str or null(float). Is there a fix here, or can you recommend another method to get this result?

**Example:**

Given dfin:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.4 | 4 | NaN |
| 'yes' | 3.2 | 5 |

I **want** to return dftypes:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| float | int | float |
| str | float | int |

(works with read_xlsx())

With read_csv() the **actual return** is:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| str | str | float |
| str | str | str |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use a try, except block to try to convert the string to float, then int, and if it succeeds return 'float' or 'int', if not return 'str'?

e.g.

```
def get_data_type(value):
    try:
        float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return 'str'
    else:
        try:
            int(value)
            return 'int'
        except ValueError:
            return 'float'

dfin.applymap(get_data_type)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this seems to work but I would add an edit casting 'value' as str -- ie. str(value)

Comment: This solution also does not handle the case of datetime

Comment: I was just trying to account for the datatypes in your example, but you could add another try, except block with pd.to_datetime(value).

Comment: Thats true, I marked this as the correct answer. I was able to make it work with some additional try-except blocks for other datatypes. Thanks